# residue class rings - value calculations with modulo

Tags: modular-arithmetic

computer science studies - residue class rings.

I have to calculate the following expression in $ \mathbb{Z_9}$

[image]

and the other one in $ \mathbb{Z_{16}}$

[image]

my question is how one should handle $-1, 23, 10$ in the "powers"?

are they really powers or do they have another meaning perhaps?

Thank you for your help

Comment: When you see $[5]_9^{10}$, (unless there is some other context you didn't report on) it really means $[5]_9 \times [5]_9 \times \ldots \times [5]_9$ ten times. But $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_n$ being a ring morphism means that this operation yields the same result as $[5^{10}]_9$.

Answer (score 1):

Here we show the OP some techniques (tricks?) for finding the inverse elements in   $\mathbb{Z_{16}}$.

Since $15 \equiv -1 \pmod{16}$ we can factor $15$ and write

$\quad 3\cdot 5 \equiv -1 \pmod{16} \; \text{ iff } \; (-3) \cdot 5 \equiv 1 \pmod{16} \; \text{ iff } \; 5 \cdot 13 \equiv 1 \pmod{16}$

and

$\quad 3\cdot 5 \equiv -1 \pmod{16} \; \text{ iff } \; 3 \cdot (-5) \equiv 1 \pmod{16} \; \text{ iff } \; 3 \cdot 11 \equiv 1 \pmod{16}$

A good start - we've found the inverse of four residue primes. By working with our 'material', we'll find $[7]^{-1}$ by multiplying $[7]$ with known quantities and see if we transform it to $[1]$.

$\quad 7 \cdot 3 \equiv 21 \pmod{16}$
$\quad 7 \cdot 3 \equiv 5 \pmod{16}$
$\quad 7 \cdot 3 \cdot 13 \equiv 5 \cdot 13 \pmod{16}$
$\quad 7 \cdot (39) \equiv 1 \pmod{16}$
$\quad 7 \cdot 7 \equiv 1 \pmod{16}$

So $[7]^{-1} = 7$.

Here are the remaining invertible elements,

$\quad \large [9]^{-1} = \bigr([3]^{2}\bigr)^{-1}  = \bigr([3]^{-1}\bigr)^2 = [11^2] = [121] = [9]$

$\quad \large [15]^{-1} = [3\cdot5]^{-1} = [3^{-1} \cdot 5^{-1}] = [11 \cdot 13] = [15]$

(there is an easier way to find $[15]^{-1}$)

$\quad \large [1]^{-1} = [1]$

So $\mathbb{Z_{16}}$ has $8 = \phi(16)$ invertible elements.

Answer (score 0):

In a ring, $x^n$ means the power. So you have, for instance, $x=[5]_9$ as an element of $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$ and you raise it to the power $10$.

What can you do here? You know that $\gcd(5,9)=1$ and therefore Euler-Fermat applies, yielding
$$
5^{\varphi(9)}=5^6\equiv1\pmod{9}
$$
Therefore
$$
[5]_9^{10}=[5_9]^6[5]_9^4=[5]_9^4=([5]_9^2)^2)=[7]_9^2=[4]_9
$$
What about $[7]_{16}^{-1}$? Hint: $7\cdot7=49$.